# Twitter login with Laravel

Tags: php, twitter, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Artdarek's lib for Laravel but I have a problem.

when users try to login with Twitter they are redirected to Twitter authenticate page and asked for permission.
But if they authorize that app Twitter redirects them to page

```
"Redirecting you back to the application. This may take a few moments."
```

and then redirect back to authenticate page on Twitter.
authenticate?oauth_token=UNbRevLchuLCYxsDlgqHODQMmA4osBHoOKbzPLdkCs

Here is my config app/config/packages/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel/config.php

```
'storage' => 'Session', 
'consumers' => array(
    'Twitter' => array(
        'client_id'         => 'xxxxxxAPI key',
        'client_secret'     => 'xxxxxxAPI secret'
    )       
)
```

and here is my login function

```
public function twiiter() {
    $code = Input::get('code');
    $oauth_verifier = Input::get( 'oauth_verifier' );
    $twitterService = OAuth::consumer('Twitter');
    if(!empty($code)) {
        $token = $twitterService->getStorage()->retrieveAccessToken('Twitter');
        $twitterService->requestAccessToken( $code, $oauth_verifier, $token->getRequestTokenSecret() );
        $result = json_decode( $twitterService->request( 'account/verify_credentials.json') );
        $user = User::where( [ 'twitter_id' => $result->id ] )->first();
        if ( $user ) {
            $user->twitter_id = $result->id;
            $user->save();
            Auth::login($user);
            return Redirect::to('/');
        } else {

        }
    } else {
        $token = $twitterService->requestRequestToken();
        $url = $twitterService->getAuthorizationUri(['oauth_token' => $token->getRequestToken()]);
        return Redirect::to((string)$url);
    }
}
```

How to fix this problem? I checked in apps.twitter and my app can Sign in with Twitter, where did I made mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Twitter doesn't use the `code` variable, rather just the `oauth_token` which you see in the redirection url.

[Here's the official example for Twitter](https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib/blob/master/examples/twitter.php), notice this line specifically:

```
if (!empty($_GET['oauth_token'])) {
```

So the reason you keep getting redirected is because no `code` querystring key is ever set, and therefore it keeps retrieving an access token etc.

Comment: A did that, now redirects back to my app but there is an error trtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given